# how to get authenticated user's project role with google cloud APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get an authenticated user's Google Cloud project role through the PHP Google Cloud API.

I have looked through the [Google Cloud Accounts API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/clouduseraccounts/vm_alpha/), the Google IAM API, and the oAuth API, but haven't found an endpoint that responds with the required information.

I would like to receive a response via the following:  I have authenticated to Google via oAuth.  I submit a project id (ie. my-test-project) to the endpoint and if I have access to a project by that name, it tells me what my role is in that project (owner, editor, viewer, or other IAM role).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact solution, but it does provide the projects that the user has access to:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
...
do client oAuth authorization steps
...
// create a BigQuery Services and see what projects it has access to
$gbq_service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
$project_list = $gbq_service->projects->listProjects();
$projects = $project_list->getProjects();
```